# slime prints my (format ...) calls only when called function ends

Tags: emacs, common-lisp, flush, sbcl, slime

I have emacs + sbcl + slime installed. I have this function defined

```
(defun jugar ()
  (let* ((nodoActual *nodo-inicial*)
         (estadoActual (nodo-estado nodoActual))
         (timeStart nil)
         (timeEnd nil)
         )
    (loop while (not (es-estado-final estadoActual)) do
          (setf *hojas* 0)
          (setf timeStart (get-universal-time))
          (setf nodoActual (decision-minimax nodoActual *profundidad* timeStart))
          (setf timeEnd (get-universal-time))
          (setf estadoActual (nodo-estado nodoActual))
          (imprime-en-fichero estadoActual)
          (format t "Hojas analizadas:     ~a  ~%" *hojas*)
          (format t "Tiempo empleado:     ~a  ~%~%" time))   
    ))
```

that makes a series of calls and print some variables in a loop.

The problem is when I call `(jugar)` from the `*slime-repl sbcl*` buffer, the prompt waits until `(jugar)` execution ends for showing all the `(format …)` together. I tried the same from a terminal (running sbcl) and it works well, so I guess it is something related to emacs or slime. How can I fix it?

Comment: I suspect it's because of buffering when output is connected to a pipe.

Comment: How can I fix it to show the formats "on the fly"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add (force-output) after last (format ) call.

Comment: Thank you! (force-output) was the solution. Now It works as it should :)

Comment: @gosku If peroksid's answer worked for you, you should [accept it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/225437) to let others know that it worked for you, to reduce the number of unanswered questions, and to give peroksid (and yourself) a bit of reputation, too.

Answer (score 7):

[proksid's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19220711/1281433) mentions `force-output`, which is on the right track, but there are actually a few related possibilities.  The [documentation for `force-output`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_finish.htm) also describes `finish-output` (and `clear-output`, which isn't relevant for us):

> **finish-output**, **force-output**, and **clear-output** exercise control over
>   the internal handling of buffered stream output.
>
> **finish-output** attempts to ensure that any buffered output sent to
>   output-stream has reached its destination, and then returns.
>
> **force-output** initiates the emptying of any internal buffers but does
>   not wait for completion or acknowledgment to return.
>
> **clear-output** attempts to abort any outstanding output operation in
>   progress in order to allow as little output as possible to continue to
>   the destination.

If you want to guarantee that the output from the different iterations doesn't get interleaved (I don't know whether this is likely or not), you might want to consider `finish-output` instead of `force-output`.  In either case, at least be aware of both options.

Comment: Thank you for all the help. (force-output) was enough due to the minimax function takes some time.