# Problems with read function in lisp

Tags: common-lisp

I'm trying to make a prompt for user input, but each time i call this function, instead of printing the ":", it waits until I press something and after that prints the character ":".

I can't find anything on the web.

```
(defun MovimientoAdversario ()
  (let ((aux))
    (format t "~% :")
    (setf aux (read))))
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [slime prints my (format ...) calls only when called function ends](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19204332/slime-prints-my-format-calls-only-when-called-function-ends)

Comment: This doesn't actually have much to do with `read`, except that it happens to be the next input/output operation.  You just need to flush the output buffer (which the possible duplicate) describes how to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [flushing the output buffers](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_finish.htm) before reading:

```common-lisp
(format t "~% :")
(force-output)
(setf aux (read))
```

Comment: Thank you very much! You save my sorry a.. . Thank you! Thank you!