# READ runs before FORMAT

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, sbcl, slime

Ran this in SLIME and wondering why it waits on `read` input before outputting `format`.

```
(defun wage ()
  (format t "~&Enter wage: ")
  (let ((wage (read)))
    (format t "~&Enter hours: ")
    (let ((hours (read)))
      (format t "~&Earned ~S dollars." (* wage hours)))))

* (wage)

2
Enter wage: 
3
Enter hours: 
Earned 6 dollars.
NIL
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [slime prints my (format ...) calls only when called function ends](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19204332/slime-prints-my-format-calls-only-when-called-function-ends)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That happens because the standard output stream is buffered, which means that things that are printed to it do not actually write to the display straight away. You need to call `(finish-output)` before `(read)` in each instance to ensure that anything that's been buffered is written first.