# Printing to screen while in loop

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, output-buffering, land-of-lisp

I have this:

```
(loop for i below x
            do (update-world)
            if (zerop (mod i 1000))
            do (princ #\.))
```

It is working, except that all the `princ` invokations arrive at once, at the end. The idea here is that they are a progress indicator, printing a period to the screen every 1000 iterations. This is from the Land of Lisp book, and I'm wondering if expecting printing in the middle of a loop is not a portable expectation?

Comment: Output can be buffered. See Lars' answer.

Comment: possible duplicate of [slime prints my (format ...) calls only when called function ends](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19204332/slime-prints-my-format-calls-only-when-called-function-ends)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add a `(finish-output)` after the `princ`.

http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_finish.htm

Comment: `finish-output` isn't the only option, though. There's also `force-output`, as described in [slime prints my (format …) calls only when called function ends](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19204332/1281433) (of which I think this question qualifies as a duplicate).